# Why is the terminal echoing my PS1 pattern at the start of every session?

Tags: bash, ps1

I have a kind of complicated PS1 pattern:

```
export PS1="\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "
```

Which is based off of the [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt) utility and docs.

Everything used to work pretty well, but for a while now, whenever I start a new terminal session my terminal seems to output some of the PS1:

```
\]\u@\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\] \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "pat@computer:~ $
```

And I can't figure out why.  Hitting enter the next ps1 output is normal:

```
\]\u@\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\] \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "pat@computer:~ $ 
pat@computer:~ $ 
pat@computer:~ $
```

Executing individual lines of my .bashrc related to PS1 configuration doesn't appear to cause shell output.

Comment: Perhaps you have `echo "$PS1"` in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`.  Did you `grep PS1` all the possible startup files?

Comment: Run `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i`, and look through its output to find the exact command responsible, complete with path to the file and line number.

Comment: (aside: *grumble* about the unnecessary use of `export` -- PS1 is a shell builtin variable; there's not generally any good reason for it to be exported to the environment, which can make it available to other, non-bash shells which won't necessarily parse it correctly).

Comment: Anyhow -- for this to be answerable, it would need to contain a [mcve] -- that is, code actually tested to produce the same result *in isolation*. That one `export` command does *not* produce the output in question on its own, meaning you need to track down what else in your dotfiles is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and apologies for the delayed response on this question. I posted it and then went on break.

I spent some time trying to create a minimal/complete/verifiable example and had some trouble, but it was some time ago, so I don't quite remember the details. I'll give it another go and let you know. 

FYI:
- I did search for PS1 in my config files and found nothing apart from my one assignment in my .bashrc. 
- duly noted that export is not required.
- PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i produced a LOT of output. Nothing stood out.